# Required custom WooCommerce checkout fields don't validate entered value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I'm adding WooCommerce custom checkout fields in a Storefront child theme **`functions.php`** file. 
They have a "required" attribute. 
The aim is to have these fields appear at the top of the page, before the billing fields.

when clicking the submit button to proceed to payment, I'm getting the required custom field validation error ('please fill in your name') and can't continue with payment, even though filling the field with valid data.

Any clue how to fix this or where to start debugging ?

here is the code in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'my_custom_checkout_fields' );

function my_custom_checkout_fields( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field" class="col4-set"><h2>' . __('name') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'developer_name', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('developer_name-class form-row form-row-first'),
        'label'         => __('name'),
        'placeholder'   => __('fill in your name'), 
        'required'      => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'developer_name' ));                               

    echo '</div>';

}

/**
 * Process the checkout
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
if ( ! $_POST['developer_name'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'please fill in your name' ), 'error' );  
}
```

---

I tried the following but none of them helped:

**1. changing:**

```php
if ( ! $_POST['developer_name'] )
```

to

```
if ( empty( $_POST['developer_name']) )
```

**2. changing the trigger from:**

```php
 add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'my_custom_checkout_fields' );
```

to

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'my_custom_checkout_fields' );
```

**3. updating to latest Woocomerce 3.0.5 version**

> I'm running Wordpress 4.7.4
>   additional related active plugins:
>   Uni CPO - WooCommerce Options and Price Calculation Formulas

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can read in **`woocommerce_before_checkout_form`** hook, it's before checkout form (so outside the checkout form). **For this reason this custom field can't work in this hook**.

You can use instead **`woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`** action hook, making some little changes in your code as there is no $checkout argument available in it.

> This will display the field **"at the top of the page, before the billing fields"**…

[image]

So your complete code should be now:

```
/**
 * Add the field to the checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details', 'my_custom_checkout_fields' );

function my_custom_checkout_fields() {

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field" class="col4-set"><h2>' . __('name') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'developer_name', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('developer_name-class form-row form-row-first'),
        'label'         => __('name'),
        'placeholder'   => __('fill in your name'),
        'required'      => true,
    ), WC()->checkout->get_value( 'developer_name' ));

    echo '</div>';

}

/**
 * Process the checkout
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( ! $_POST['developer_name'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please fill in your name.' ), 'error' );
}


// Update the order meta with field value
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['developer_name'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Developer name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['developer_name'] ) );
    }
}

// Display the custom-field in orders view
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_customer_details', 'display_my_custom_field_in_orde_details', 10, 1 );
function display_my_custom_field_in_orde_details( $order ) {

    $developer_name = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'Developer name',  true );

    if ( ! empty( $developer_name ) ):
    ?>
        <table class="woocommerce-table woocommerce-table--customer-details shop_table customer_details">
            <tbody><tr>
                <th>Developer name:</th>
                <td><?php echo $developer_name; ?></td>
            </tr></tbody>
        </table>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works for WooCommerce version 3.0+

Comment: Thank you ! this answers the question and works well

Answer (score 1):

You try this code. Tested Ok

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'my_custom_checkout_fields' );

function my_custom_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

   $fields['billing_developer_name'] = array(
    'label'       => __('Developer name', 'woocommerce'),            
    'placeholder' => _x('Developer name', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),  
    'required'    => TRUE,             
    'clear'       => false,             
    'type'        => 'text',              
    'class'       => array('my-css')    
    );

 return $fields;

}
```

You can arrange it with this snippet

```
add_filter("woocommerce_checkout_fields", "order_fields");

function order_fields($fields) {

    $order = array(
        "billing_developer_name",
        "billing_first_name", 
        "billing_last_name", 
        "billing_company", 
        "billing_address_1", 
        "billing_address_2", 
        "billing_postcode", 
        "billing_country", 
        "billing_email", 
        "billing_phone"

    );
    foreach($order as $field)
    {
        $ordered_fields[$field] = $fields["billing"][$field];
    }

    $fields["billing"] = $ordered_fields;
    return $fields;

}
```

See [screenshot](https://i.screenshot.net/e5r9gfp)

Comment: i forgot to make it clear. my aim is to have these fields located before the billing information. that means on the top of the page. your solution is good but the custom fields appear below the billing fields.

Comment: @buzibuzi : Updated

Comment: it works, can these field-set have a title above and below them ? with my checkout code i have a H2 title printed above them. "Billing Details" title comes below them, so have some kind of a separator between the fields.

Comment: great approach, thank you. @LoicTheAztec answer fits my need more because it keeps the custom fields on the top as a separate section from the Billing section

Answer (score 1):

```
**/* If You Have Created Your Custom Field at the checkout page */**

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'shipping_time_optionss', 9999, 2);
function shipping_time_optionss( $fields, $errors ){
    // if any validation errors
    if ( empty( $_POST['woo_shipping_time'] ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'woocommerce_password_error', __( 'Please Select Shipping Time Option.' ) );
    } `enter code here`
}
```