# Display a custom-field value in Woocommerce orders edit view

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

I have a similar like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43717227/3730754): I don't understand why the value of this custom field is not saved. Here's my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'altri_campi' );

function altri_campi( $fields ) {
$fields['billing']['codice_fiscale'] = array(
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label'     => __('Codice Fiscale', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Scrivere anche il Codice Fiscale', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide')
    );

    return $fields;

}    

// like LoizTheAztec above
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 10, 1 );
    function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['codice_fiscale'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Codice Fiscale', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['codice_fiscale'] ) );
        }
    }

    // then I'm expecting that custom field value will be saved somehow, but won't

    add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

    function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Codice Fiscale', 'woocommerce').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_codice_fiscale', true ) . '</p>';
    }
```

Meta field is correctly saved and printed, but I cannot add the custom field value in the order data view.

What I am doing wrong and how to display this custom field value in the Order edit view?

Otherwise the text I expect to find after Customer's billing and shipping data is void, since I read only the html part of the latest snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the correct commented and explained code:

```
// Creating and displaying the custom checkout field in checkout page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'altri_campi' );
function altri_campi( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['codice_fiscale'] = array(
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label'     => __('Codice Fiscale', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Scrivere anche il Codice Fiscale', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide')
    );
    return $fields;
}

// Saving the custom checkout field value in the order meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['codice_fiscale'] ) ){
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'codice_fiscale', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['codice_fiscale'] ) );

        // get the customer ID
        $customer_id = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', true );

        // Update customer user data
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'codice_fiscale', true );
    }
}

// Displaying the custom checkout field value in the order edit page (backend)
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta( $order ){
    $codice_fiscale = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'codice_fiscale', true );
    if( ! empty( $codice_fiscale ))
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Codice Fiscale', 'woocommerce').':</strong> ' . $codice_fiscale . '</p>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> Tested and works. You will get in backend order edit page something like *(below addresses)*:
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just two notices: I had to get rid of additional "_" underscore symbol when using both in update_post_meta( $order_id, '_codice_fiscale',...) and in get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_codice_fiscale',...) otherwise the data won't be saved correctly among metas and won't be printed in the order details.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you should edit your answer by getting rid of the additional underscore symbol, otherwise I can't confirm your answer worked for me 100%. :)

Comment: is there a way to add the same meta for the order also for customer? I mean, is it possible to use update_user_meta?