# Woocommerce Custom product fields need to be editable after purchase in View Orders Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am Using [Display a custom-field value in Woocommerce orders edit view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612499/display-a-custom-field-value-in-woocommerce-orders-edit-view/#answer-46615303) answer code, which works fine.

I want to display that checkout custom fields on My Account > View Order Pages, to allow customer to edit its value after purchase, so Customers can change and save the custom field value.

Any help?

Comment: Odds are you can hook into or overwrite /woocommerce/myaccount/view-order.php, which is the template that displays orders individually for users. There is not form on that page, however, so you will need to create your own form.

Comment: @james I want to make this one using functions.