# Required custom WooCommerce checkbox checkout field don't validate itself

Tags: wordpress, forms, woocommerce, checkout

I've got problem with validating checkbox in WooCommerce custom checkout field. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715891/required-custom-woocommerce-checkout-fields-dont-validate-entered-value) but it doesn't really help me. Custom field is generated inside form, so It should work good. I don't know if there is a need to put something more than my code in this particular case... I've tried few more hooks, but It doesn't made any effect.

```
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'my_required_checkout_field');

function my_required_checkout_field( ) {

    woocommerce_form_field( 'przetwarzanie_danych_do_zamowienia', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('input-checkbox'),
        'label'         => __('REQUIRED ONE.'),
        'required'  => true,
        ), WC()->checkout->get_value( 'przetwarzanie_danych_do_zamowienia' ));

}

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;
}


/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ($_POST['przetwarzanie_danych_do_zamowienia']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Oświadczenie o zapoznaniu się z regulaminem',     esc_attr($_POST['przetwarzanie_danych_do_zamowienia']));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not adding the condition when your check box is not checked you have empty function `my_custom_checkout_field_process` so here is full working code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'my_required_checkout_field');

function my_required_checkout_field()
{

    woocommerce_form_field('przetwarzanie_danych_do_zamowienia', array(
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'class' => array('input-checkbox'),
        'label' => __('REQUIRED ONE.'),
        'required' => true,
    ), WC()->checkout->get_value('przetwarzanie_danych_do_zamowienia'));

}

/**
 * Process the checkout
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process()
{

    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if (!$_POST['przetwarzanie_danych_do_zamowienia']) {

        wc_add_notice(__('Please select required box'), 'error');
    }

}

/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id)
{
    if ($_POST['przetwarzanie_danych_do_zamowienia']) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'Oświadczenie o zapoznaniu się z regulaminem', esc_attr($_POST['przetwarzanie_danych_do_zamowienia']));
    }

}
```